# how to rename an ontology's prefixes

Tags: java, rdf, jena, ontology, owl

I have created an onology using Jena API which contains the following classes and DataType Properties:

```
public class Onto {
 OntClass USER,...;

 OntModel model;

        String uriBase;
        DatatypeProperty Name,Surname,..;
 ObjectProperty has_EDUCATION_LEVEL;
public Onto (){
            model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_MICRO_RULE_INF );
            uriBase = "http://www.something.com/";
            model.createOntology(uriBase);

            //Classes
 USER=model.createClass(uriBase+"USER");

...

   //DatatTypesProperties   
            Name= model.createDatatypeProperty(uriBase+"Name"); 
            Name.setDomain(USER_AUTNENTIFICATION);
            Name.setRange(XSD.xstring);

Surname= model.createDatatypeProperty(uriBase+"Surname"); 
            Surname.setDomain(USER_AUTNENTIFICATION);
            Surname.setRange(XSD.xstring);
...

   //ObjectProperties
            has_EDUCATION_LEVEL= model.createObjectProperty(uriBase+"has_EDUCATION_LEVEL");
            has_EDUCATION_LEVEL.setDomain(USER);
            has_EDUCATION_LEVEL.setRange(EDUCATION_LEVEL);}
```

Then i created and instance of Class the "USER" in which i inserted some values for the DataType Properties "Name" and "Surname" Throught a Web. My code's output is a .owl file.But when i read it with Protege Ifound out that all of my Data Properties , my Object Properties and even my classes contains tow prefixes j.1 and j.0 .
Here is the code of my instance in OWL file:

```
 <j.1:USER rdf:about="http://www.something.com/#Jhon">
    <j.0:has_EDUCATION_LEVEL rdf:resource="http://www.something.com/HIGH_EDUCATION_LEVEL"/>
    <j.0:Surname>Smith</j.0:Surname>
    <j.0:Name>Jhon</j.0:Name>
  </j.1:USER>
```

i would be thankful for any help or sugestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll see somewhere at the beginning of your RDF/XML document that the prefixes `j.1` and `j.0` are defined appropriately, so that `http://www.something.com/has_EDUCATION_LEVEL` is the same as `j.0:has_EDUCATION_LEVEL`.   Jena's not doing anything that changes the property URIs, so if you read your model back in, or send it to someone else, they'll still see exactly the same data.  The prefixes used only matter to humans reading the XML text.

That said, a Jena model is a [PrefixMapping](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/shared/PrefixMapping.html), so you can use `setNsPrefix` to define the names and prefixes that will be used when writing the model.  Here's an example, loosely based on the data you provided:

```
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;

public class PrefixDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    String base = "http://www.something.com/";

    Resource john = model.createResource( base + "John" );
    Property hasSurname = model.createProperty( base + "hasSurname" );

    model.add( john, hasSurname, "Smith" );

    // Before defining a prefix
    model.write( System.out, "RDF/XML" );

    // After defining a prefix
    model.setNsPrefix( "something", base );
    model.write( System.out, "RDF/XML" );
  }
}
```

The output (with an extra newline between models) is:

```
<rdf:RDF
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:j.0="http://www.something.com/" > 
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.something.com/John">
    <j.0:hasSurname>Smith</j.0:hasSurname>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>

<rdf:RDF
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:something="http://www.something.com/" > 
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.something.com/John">
    <something:hasSurname>Smith</something:hasSurname>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

The first time the model is printed, you'll see the automatically generated namespace prefix `j.0`.  When we explicitly define a prefix, however, it gets used, as in the second example.